# How to deploy java springboot project on google cloud run

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I am trying to deploy java project as an API via github to google cloud run but I keep getting permission denied. Here is the error I keep getting:

*Buildpack": Failure: (ID: dc066188) executing command "./mvnw clean package --batch-mode -DskipTests -Dhttp.keepAlive=false -f=pom.xml --quiet": fork/exec ./mvnw: permission denied *

I have tried building the project with docker but I wasn't able to do that. I was able to push the project successfully to cloud run via github but the project doesn't build successfully. I tried changing the line endings to LF on visual studio code and github but it didn't bring a fix. Lastly, I also tried making the mvnw executable which didn't fix it still.

This is my cloud.yaml configuration file if it is any help

steps:

- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/mvn'
  args: ['clean', 'install', '-DskipTests']
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  args: ['run', 'deploy', 'favdoctorapi', '--image', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/favdoctorapi', '--platform', 'managed', '--region', 'us-central1']
  dir: './'

Comment: What command do you run? Can you share more about your pipeline, dockerfile (if any) or whatever you do?

Comment: I didn't use dockerfile. I have added the cloud.yaml i used for the configuration to the question

Comment: What's the linux permission of ./mvnw binary?

Comment: I set it to executable

Comment: Strange because it's exactly the meaning of your error!